# Pop Up modal only works on first item

Tags: javascript, jquery, shopify

I am working on a shopify store, there is a 'remove from cart' option on the cart page, when they click on it a popup shows up to confirm if they want to remove it from the cart. 
The issue I am having is that the popup will only work on the first item, the others will just take you back to the top of the page.

Here's the code I am using.

The remove text

```
<td style="text-align: center">
            <a href="#" id="cart_popup">X</a>
</td>
```

The Popup

```
<!-- The Modal -->
    <div id="myModal" class="modal">

      <!-- Modal content -->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <p class="modal-index-title">Hey!</p>
        <p class="modal-title">Are you sure you want to remove this?</p>
        <div class="modal-confirm">
          <span class="close">No!</span>
          <p><a href="#" onclick="remove_item({{ item.variant.id }}); return false;">Yes</a></p>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
```

The script

```
  // Get the modal
  var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

  // Get the button that opens the modal
  var btn = document.getElementById("cart_popup");

  // Get the <span> element that closes the modal
  var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

  // When the user clicks on the button, open the modal 
  btn.onclick = function() {
      modal.style.display = "block";
  }

  // When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
  span.onclick = function() {
      modal.style.display = "none";
  }

  // When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
  window.onclick = function(event) {
      if (event.target == modal) {
          modal.style.display = "none";
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IDs are supposed to be unique for a DOM element so your JS code will just grab the first instance of the `cart_popup` element and apply the onClick there.

If you want to make it apply across all your remove cart buttons, add a CSSclass to it and then apply the `btn.onclick` function to buttons having that class.

EDIT:

Example:

```
var classname = document.getElementsByClassName("classname");

var showModal = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
};

for (var i = 0; i < classname.length; i++) {
    classname[i].addEventListener('click', showModal, false);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Erick and that makes sense!
Would you be able to give me an example, I just tried applying a CSSclass, but that caused it not to load.

Comment: Well you'll have to fundamentally change your code to make it work with a class, as if you use a class selector instead, the Javascript code will return an array of elements instead (because there's more than one using the class)

I've edited my answer to add a sample code.

Answer (score 0):

You might have several elements with the same `id` attribute. Only the first triggers your `btn.onclick` function.